# Promise not returning any data for fetch return

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, promise, express-router

I´m building an express router that uses mongoose to access the database. My current problem relies on this piece of code:

```
app.use("/authreset", (req, res) => {
    authenticator
        .resetPassword(
            req.body.username,
            req.body.password,
            req.body.token,
            req.body.type
        )
        .then((response, error) => {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);

            console.log('*****************');
            console.log(response);

            if (!response) {
                res.sendStatus(401);
                return;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('*****************');
            console.log(error);
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
        });

});
```

resetPassword uses the following mongoose call:

```
return UserModel
    .findByIdAndUpdate(user.id, data, { new: true })
    .exec();
```

For some reason, my route is being called and the response is fine (checked on `console.log(response)` inside promise).

My problem is that the response is never sent back to the client, that times out the fetch call.

Why is my promise not returning data?

Comment: which promise is meant to return data, and where is it meant to return data to? - can't see anything returning data, nor even sending data in a response in the code you posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh, you log the `response`, but you never `send` it (or at least respond with a status code)?

Your code should look more like

```
app.use("/authreset", (req, res) => {
    authenticator.resetPassword(
        req.body.username,
        req.body.password,
        req.body.token,
        req.body.type
    ).then(response => {
        console.log(response);

        if (!response) {
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        } else {
            return res.sendStatus(200); // <<<
        }
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        return res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

Notice that the `then` callback never gets called with more than one argument, so that `error` you were checking for cannot happen. In the `catch` handler, you should never re`throw` an error if it doesn't get handled further down. Also I [changed `.then(…).catch(…)` to the more fitting `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572).

Comment: In fact I don´t need the reponse on the client, just the status. 401 failed, 200 succeeded. I removed the `res.send(response)` and my client is still stuck...

Comment: Nothing, but I got the problem. I need `return res.sendStatus(200)` or whatever. I will edit your code. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation to go along with the code?

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah, the OPs edit removed the main part of my explanation, didn't notice that